# Will I be able to use Scale sets feature in Azure if I have a dependency where a manual input needs to be given for every new instance of VM Scale set

Tags: azure, key, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Will I be able to use Scale sets feature in Azure if I have a dependency where a manual input SHOULD needs to be given for every new VM initiated in Scale set( an OTP should be entered manually which is generated based on the key generated by the application which runs on new VM initiated as part of scale set)  any suggestions or think of an alternative approach with which we can still use scale sets.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is your manual factor.

> Azure virtual machine scale sets let you create and manage a group of
> load balanced VMs. The number of VM instances can automatically
> increase or decrease in response to demand or a defined schedule.

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview

Comment: manual factors for my case are I need to enter a otp received in my phone to enable my s/w application running on new VM with in a scale set.